# Why does the CSS only apply when refreshed?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[Div CSS loading issue](https://streamable.com/zxwec8)

I have a simple php login system where the button calls on the JavaScript function `loading()` in order to display a div and an mp4 over the login. Kind of like a loading screen that always takes the same duration. The issue I have is whenever I load up the page the div and mp4 css isn't applied, resulting in it being displayed as shown in the video.

If I wait for the mp4 to end however and try again, (or even using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> to refresh) it fixes the issue and displays normally.

Am I doing something wrong resulting in this?

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

```js
function loading() {
  var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
  overlay.style.display = 'flex';
}
```

```css
.overlay {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #62a6ff;
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border-color: #85baff;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 2px #000000;
}

.videoframe {
  margin-top: 25%;
  margin-left: 7%;
  width: 300;
  height: 169;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 2px #000000;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.backvideo {
  width: 300;
  height: 169;
}
```

```html
<input class="button" id="submit" type="submit" value="Login" onclick="loading()">
<br>
<br>
<div id="pagechange2"><a href="signup.php">SignUp</a></div>
</form>
</div>
<div id="overlay" class="overlay" style="display:none">
  <div id="videoframe" class="videoframe">
    <video class="backvideo" autoplay muted crossOrigin="anonymous">
                    <source src="videos/background3s.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVRd7.png)

Comment: can you inspect your video and get a screenshot of the element in the dev tool(the abnormal one)?

Comment: Maybe, the lack of an unit to the width and height is the only problem? Did you try to fix that retaining the class? (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width)

Comment: I did but it didn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it and got it to work.
I changed the following:

```
<video class="backvideo" autoplay muted crossOrigin="anonymous">
```

to:

```
<video id="backvideo" autoplay muted crossOrigin="anonymous">
```

I changed the `class` to an `id`

I then went to my CSS and changed `.backvideo` to `#backvideo` and then changed

```
.videoframe {
  margin-top: 25%;
  margin-left: 7%;
  width: 300;
  height: 169;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 2px #000000;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.backvideo {
  width: 300;
  height: 169;
}
```

to:

```
.videoframe{
    margin-top: 25%;
    margin-left: 7%;
    width: 300px;
    height: 169px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 2px #000000;
    background-color: #000000;
 }

 #backvideo{
    width: 300px;
    height: 169px;
 }
```

adding `px` to both the `width` and `height` values